# Sort dates through file name date

Tags: python, sorting, date

I have a folder with *.txt files which contain a specific format (c is character and d is digit and yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss is the date format)

cccccd_ddd_cc_ccc_c_dd-ddd_yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss.txt

or

cccccd_ddd_cc_ccc_c_dd-dddd_yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss.txt

or

cccccd_ddd_cc_ccc_c_d_yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss.txt

when the single digidt d is equal to 0

I would like to create a python script to obtain the dates and sort the files from that specific date.

SO far I ahve done

```
import os
list_files=[]
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        #print(file)
        list_files.append(file)
```

But I am bit new with regular expressions. Thanks

Comment: You don't need regular expressions to parse this string. You can use `.split()` to tokenize your filenames.

Comment: Hi @JPV, if my answer has helped you, could you please mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.split()` to split a string.
It seems that we can split from the last occurence of "_", remove the part after "." to get the timestamp. 
So, method to return timestamp from the file_name is:

```
def get_timestamp(file_name):
    return file_name.split("_")[-1].split('.')[0]
```

As all the dates are of same format, python can sort those using the timestamp string itself.
To get the sorted list of filenames using that timestamp, you can do:

```
sorted_list = sorted(list_files, key=get_timestamp)
```

More about the [Key](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) function can be learned from official python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in the an array called `inFiles`. Use the following line of code to arrange them based on the date in the string:

```
inFiles = sorted(inFiles, key=lambda file_name:datetime.strptime(os.path.basename(file_name).split('_')[2],"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"))
```